# WHERE clause subquery doesn't return all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause

When I run this query

```
select SFRSTCA_CRN       CRN,
   SFRSTCA_BILL_HR   Cr_Hr,
   SFRSTCA_Seq_Number Seq_no       
  from chelink.tmp_stca_201470 
  where SFRSTCA_PIDM = 9573001 
    and SFRSTCA_RSTS_DAte <= '15-oct-14'
```

I get the following results

```
CRN        CR_HR     SEQ_NO
----- ---------- ----------
74705          1         30 
74705          1         37 
74707          1          9 
74707          1         15 
75093          3          4 
75093          3         14 
75093          3         21 
75627          3          5 
75627          3         13 
75627          3         22 
75627          0         33 
77320          3          6 
77320          3         12 
77320          3         23 
77320          3         35 
77776          3         10 
77776          3         11 
78615          3         31 
78615          3         36
```

When I try to find the maximum Seq_No for each CRN by using a subquery in the where clause, using this query

```
SELECT CRN,
       Cr_Hr,
       Seq_No       
FROM
(select SFRSTCA_CRN       CRN,
        SFRSTCA_PIDM      PIDM,
        SFRSTCA_BILL_HR   Cr_Hr,
        SFRSTCA_Seq_Number Seq_no       
  from chelink.tmp_stca_201470  
  where SFRSTCA_PIDM = 9573001  
   and SFRSTCA_RSTS_DAte <= '15-oct-14'
) STCA_List
WHERE Seq_No = 
      (SELECT Max(SFRSTCA_Seq_Number)
         FROM chelink.tmp_stca_201470 STCA2
        WHERE STCA2.SFRSTCA_PIDM = STCA_List.PIDM
          AND STCA2.SFRSTCA_CRN  = STCA_List.CRN
      )
```

These are the results.  One of the CRN's missing (75093).  What gives?

```
CRN        CR_HR     SEQ_NO
----- ---------- ----------
74705          1         37 
74707          1         15 
75627          0         33 
77320          3         35 
77776          3         11 
78615          3         36
```

Comment: I imagine your max subquery is finding a sequence for that CRN that is after 15-Oct-14? Why not include the same condirions in the subquery? (Although the whole thing could be written more simply and efficiently anyway; and relying on implicit conversions isn't a good diea). We can't see your raw data to check though.

Comment: I have tried to replicate your problem,I did not face any issue. I have ignored the PIDM column and the STCA2.SFRSTCA_PIDM = STCA_List.PIDM condition. I guess there is some issue in your PIDM condition.

Comment: That was it!  I needed to include the date criteria in the where subquery.  Although having this problem allowed me to find a simpler solution using Analytics.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Alex!  I'm always interested in learning more efficient and simpler methods.  Do you have time to share a suggested improvement?

Comment: OK, expanded that comment into an answer, and included a simpler method - one that doesn't even need analytics (I guess you were getting row_number() or a rank inside the subquery instead?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table only contained the values you showed:

```
create table tmp_stca_201470 (sfrstca_crn number, sfrstca_bill_hr number,
  sfrstca_seq_number number , sfrstca_pidm number, sfrstca_rsts_date date);

insert into tmp_stca_201470 (sfrstca_crn, sfrstca_bill_hr,
  sfrstca_seq_number, sfrstca_pidm, sfrstca_rsts_date)
select 74705, 1, 30, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 74705, 1, 37, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 74707, 1, 9, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 74707, 1, 15, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75093, 3, 4, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75093, 3, 14, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75093, 3, 21, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75627, 3, 5, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75627, 3, 13, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75627, 3, 22, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 75627, 0, 33, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77320, 3, 6, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77320, 3, 12, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77320, 3, 23, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77320, 3, 35, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77776, 3, 10, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 77776, 3, 11, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 78615, 3, 31, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual
union all select 78615, 3, 36, 9573001, date '2014-10-15' from dual;
```

then you would get the result you expected:

```
select sfrstca_crn crn,
  sfrstca_bill_hr cr_hr,
  sfrstca_seq_number seq_no 
from tmp_stca_201470 
where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001 
and sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15';

       CRN      CR_HR     SEQ_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
     74705          1         30
...
... same 19 rows you had
```

and from your second query:

```
select crn, cr_hr, seq_no
from (
  select sfrstca_crn crn,
    sfrstca_pidm pidm,
    sfrstca_bill_hr cr_hr,
    sfrstca_seq_number seq_no
  from tmp_stca_201470  
  where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001  
  and sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15'
) stca_list
where seq_no = (
  select max(sfrstca_seq_number)
  from tmp_stca_201470 stca2
  where stca2.sfrstca_pidm = stca_list.pidm
  and stca2.sfrstca_crn  = stca_list.crn
);

       CRN      CR_HR     SEQ_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
     74705          1         37
     74707          1         15
     75093          3         21
     75627          0         33
     77320          3         35
     77776          3         11
     78615          3         36

7 rows selected.
```

The apparent problem comes if you have a row with a higher sequence number and with a date outside the range you're filtering on:

```
insert into tmp_stca_201470 (sfrstca_crn, sfrstca_bill_hr,
  sfrstca_seq_number, sfrstca_pidm, sfrstca_rsts_date)
values (75093, 42, 42, 9573001, date '2014-10-16');
```

The first query still gets the same 19 rows, as the new one is outside the range. But the second one gets the result you actually saw:

```
select crn, cr_hr, seq_no
from (
  select sfrstca_crn crn,
    sfrstca_pidm pidm,
    sfrstca_bill_hr cr_hr,
    sfrstca_seq_number seq_no
  from tmp_stca_201470  
  where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001  
  and sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15'
) stca_list
where seq_no = (
  select max(sfrstca_seq_number)
  from tmp_stca_201470 stca2
  where stca2.sfrstca_pidm = stca_list.pidm
  and stca2.sfrstca_crn  = stca_list.crn
);
       CRN      CR_HR     SEQ_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
     74705          1         37
     74707          1         15
     75627          0         33
     77320          3         35
     77776          3         11
     78615          3         36

6 rows selected.
```

If you ran the subquery on its own, getting the correlation value, you'd see:

```
select sfrstca_crn, max(sfrstca_seq_number)
from tmp_stca_201470
where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001
group by sfrstca_crn;

SFRSTCA_CRN MAX(SFRSTCA_SEQ_NUMBER)
----------- -----------------------
      75627                      33
      77320                      35
      74707                      15
      75093                      42
      78615                      36
      77776                      11
      74705                      37

7 rows selected.
```

but the sequence that finds for 75093 is 42, which isn't in the list of 19 values from the first query.

You can modify the subquery to restrict on the same date range:

```
select crn, cr_hr, seq_no
from (
  select sfrstca_crn crn,
    sfrstca_pidm pidm,
    sfrstca_bill_hr cr_hr,
    sfrstca_seq_number seq_no
  from tmp_stca_201470  
  where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001  
  and sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15'
) stca_list
where seq_no = (
  select max(sfrstca_seq_number)
  from tmp_stca_201470 stca2
  where stca2.sfrstca_pidm = stca_list.pidm
  and stca2.sfrstca_crn  = stca_list.crn
  and stca2.sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15'
);

       CRN      CR_HR     SEQ_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
     74705          1         37
     74707          1         15
     75093          3         21
     75627          0         33
     77320          3         35
     77776          3         11
     78615          3         36

7 rows selected.
```

But you can get the same result with a much simpler query that only hits the table once, using [the `last()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm):

```
select sfrstca_crn crn,
  max(sfrstca_bill_hr) keep (dense_rank last order by sfrstca_seq_number) cr_hr,
  max(sfrstca_seq_number) seq_no
from tmp_stca_201470  
where sfrstca_pidm = 9573001  
and sfrstca_rsts_date <= date '2014-10-15'
group by sfrstca_crn;

       CRN      CR_HR     SEQ_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
     74705          1         37
     74707          1         15
     75093          3         21
     75627          0         33
     77320          3         35
     77776          3         11
     78615          3         36

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the suggested improvement.  I appreciate you taking the time to find what was a dumb error in my logic that I should have been more diligent to find on my own.  There are actually over 300,000 records in the table.  I just pulled a small case to post here.  I've never used dense_rank (there's a lot to learn in Oracle).  I'll play with it.  Thanks again!